# Microsoft botframework chatbot integration with Dynamic 365 customer service omnichannel

Tags: botframework, chatbot, handoff, dynamic365

I am trying to integrate chatbot with D365 customer service omnichannel for agent handoff. I have followed all the  steps as per Microsoft documentation. still no details related how the messages are sending to the omnichannel from chat bot using webchat using direct line (**not the widget from omnichannel**) .

I was able to initiate handoff from chat widget provided by the omnichannel.
But I would like to know is it possible to use my own webchat to initiate the handoff through directline channel?

following links are used as reference for doing this.

[Provision Omnichannel for Customer Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-service/omnichannel-provision-license?WT.mc_id=BA-MVP-5000785)

[Integrate an Azure bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-service/configure-bot)